# How to fix Android ndk-build : no type named 'shared_mutex' in namespace 'std'?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

My Android.mk file contains:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions

LOCAL_CPP_FLAGS += -std=c++17

LOCAL_MODULE    := testlib

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

My Application.mk file contains:

```
APP_ABI := all
APP_PLATFORM := android-24
APP_STL := c++_static
```

My test.cpp file contains:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <shared_mutex>

std::shared_mutex myMutex;

jstring
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_string2FromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz )
{
    myMutex.lock();

}
```

When I run ndk-build I get:

error: no type named 'shared_mutex' in namespace 'std'

How do I solve this?

Comment: Typo:- change `LOCAL_CPP_FLAGS` -> `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS` ? see https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk#local_cppflags

Comment: You are a God @richardCritten !!!!! Thank you thank you thank you...i was losing my mind here!